# UIImagePickerController issue when Present

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

i am really frustrated about this issue...when i try to present UIImagePickerController..it shows the number of images..but not those all images.Can anyone help..[image]

```
UIImagePickerController *imgPickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

imgPickerController.delegate=self;

imgPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentViewController:imgPickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

Comment: What is com in last line of code.???

Comment: @mani murugan:You click the tableviewcell, which contains the disclosure button it show all the image..

Comment: @ShreyanshShah please read again

Comment: Please speak in English, so that others can understand.

Comment: this code is correctly working in  IOS 7..but not in IOS 6 ...

Answer (score 1):

Can you like this?

```
UIImagePickerController *image_picker = [UIImagePickerController new];
        image_picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        image_picker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        image_picker.delegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:image_picker animated:YES];
```

Comment: i uploaded more images in simulator. and also tested on device.

Answer (score 0):

i have added new category file for UIView..that was the issue..now i dont have that issue when i remove that category file from my project...